# Canvas game Json function only works on web inspector

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, canvas

i'm making a HTML5 game and i'm using a matriz to store the map. But now i'm using $getJson to read that values through a json file and it works, but the problem is when a change the value of my matrix through the web inspector the map changes but when i call that function directly on code i get an error:

```
game.js:51TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'levels.Level1')
```

line 51:  `mapa.loadMap(levels.Level1.board);`

Why this only works when a call the function "mapa.loadMap(levels.Level1.board)" on web inspector?

```
function map(){

    this.loadMap = function (l){
    var j= 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
    var object = l[i];
    for (property in object) {
        var value = object[property];
        this.board[j][property] = value;
    }
    j++;
    }
    }

    this.width = 10;
    this.height = 8;
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = "images/level1/tiles.png";

    this.board = [  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [8, 0, 0, 0, 33, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
            [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0],
            [25, 26, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 38, 0, 0],
            [27, 28, 5, 5, 6, 7, 0, 38, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 5, 39, 5, 5],
                    ];

   (...)
```

Forget that XD

My code is a mess because it's a sketch but i solved with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    init();

});

$(window).load(function () {
    console.log(levels.Level1.board);
    mapa = new map();  
    render();  
});
```

Thanks for helping :)
And sorry for my english XD

Comment: Anyway we could see more code? It sounds like `board` is not being defined somewhere.

Comment: This is probably an problem with *when* two pieces of code are running. Perhaps when the code runs naturally, some variable has not yet been defined, but when you run it in the console, the page has fully loaded and the necessary vars are set.

Comment: I also thought that but i used the $(document).ready and nothing :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    init();

});

$(window).load(function () {
    console.log(levels.Level1.board);
    mapa = new map();  
    render();  
});
```